# Set equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, set

I have C# code like this:

```
  if (OldStatus = activityStatus.Complete) or (OldStatus = activityStatus.Cancelled)...
```

In Delphi I would have written

```
  if OldStatus in (Complete, Cancelled) then...
```

Is there any equivalent to this use of a set in C# or do I need to spell out each option as above (or use a switch/case). (Sorry if the question is basic; I'm new to C#.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no language feature for this. You can simulate it by "spelling it out" as you say, or with an if/else chain, a switch, using a `HashSet<T>`, etc. -- the proper answer is case-specific, they're all valid in different circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an `enum` value, and that `enum` is marked with the `[Flags]` attribute, then you could use a bitmask to determine if the required value is present - as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c), otherwise, the switch, if/else etc.. apply.